# How to implement TestNG in Keyword-driven and Data-driven frame work?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to Selenium and i want to crate a test case of my dummy website for practice purpose. I have learn about Keyword-driven and Data-driven frame work. I also learned about TestNG but i am in a confusion that how to implement all these things, I want to automate full website with reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of orthogonal concepts together. Rather than unpack them, please allow me to start from the beginning.

First, you want to use the [Page Object Pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) with Selenium. This pattern decouples your tests from the internal structure of a page--via a services abstraction where all the test "knows about" is the services *provided* by the page. This way the structure of a page can change (as it certainly will during the project), but your tests remain the same (assuming the services don't change, but of course you want the tests to change in that case).

Next, you have tests that will use [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) and other aspects of the Selenium API to perform `assert`'s and `verify`'s on the page objects. These tests can be written as TestNG or JUnit tests.

So you will have a TestNG test (since that seems your preference) where the test methods will perform `assert`'s and `verify`'s on page objects by using the Selenium API.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were seeking for is `@DataProvider`, which `TestNG` provides.

All you need is to return data in type `:Object[][]` or `Iterator<Object[]>` ,then use this data provider in your testcase.

The testcase will be run (length of your `Object[][]` or `Iterator<Object[]>`) times